# Posting a question, which "Can be a duplicate" but not an EXACT DUPLICATE

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, ethics

I have a programming question which is similar to some posts in SO, but neither an exact match to my scenario nor providing adequate information. Although some posts were helpful and I povided upvotes too. 
So, should I post such a question which can be a potential duplicate but not an exact one?  Since the question has bugged me for days and I never was successful to get to the end of it.

Appreciate any sort of help on this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have already done some substantial research before posting. From that research you already learned that they seem to have just a little twist that doesn't quite fit your situation.

Your potential question should be build-up around that research. Something like this:

> I've a similar issue described in [Foo] and [Bar] but in my situation I have also to deal with FuBar.
>
> I used the answer from [Foo] to give the result A but I can't use the upvoted answer from [Bar] because the compiler complains about unicorns.
>
> I assumed that adding waffles to [Foo] and [Bar] would make things fly. (added an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible)
>
> What is the correct approach to FuBar?

Make sure to add (code) examples and compiler and test-output if relevant that also shows that the other approaches indeed don't give the desired result. Try to keep in mind that **you** have to make sure that the regulars in that tag get convinced it is not a duplicate. A clear statement on what is special/different in your context is key!

Avoid to only mention (without any evidence) that your question is not a duplicate because that is almost always a direct reason for a close vote.

Comment: *+1 and Accepted*.  That information was very much helpful. Will post now. Keeping all this in mind